# WordPressの投稿画面で、アイキャッチ画像が投稿できません

Tags: php, wordpress

#### 前提・実現したいこと

WordPressの投稿画面で、アイキャッチ画像も投稿したい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

WordPressのダッシュボードから、「投稿」「新規追加」で「新規投稿を追加」画面が出て来ますが、右下に出るはずの「アイキャッチ画像」の項目が表示されないため、アイキャッチ画像を入力できません。

#### 該当のソースコード

`functions.php`には、下記の記述をしています。

```
<?php
/**
 *アイキャッチ画像を使用可能にする
 */
add_theme_support('post_thumbnails' );
```

#### 試したこと

WordPressのダッシュボードから、「投稿」「新規追加」で「新規投稿を追加」の画面で、「表示オプション」を開きましたが、「アイキャッチ画像」のボックスは表示されていません。

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

環境

- WordPress 4.8  2017.7.6時点で最新バージョン
- レンタルサーバ：ドメインキング　Pプラン
- PHP 7.0.10（実行タイプ:FastCGIアプリケーション）
- MySQL 5.6（データベースサーバ　127.0.0.1:3316）
- Windows 10 HOME 64ビット 10.0.10011.16384
- Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0
- EdgeHTML 14.14393
- Googlechrome 57.0.2987.133

Comment: マルチポスト： https://teratail.com/questions/83063 (解決済)

Answer (score 2):

投稿サムネイル(アイキャッチ)を追加する際の引数は

```
add_theme_support('post_thumbnails');
```

ではなく

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
```

です。実際のコードでもタイプミスがあるかご確認ください。